# Saving API as environment variable (for setting up monkeylearn in R)

Tags: r, api, environment-variables, monkeylearn

I would like to use the named entity recognition functions in the monkeylearn package in R.

As part of the setting up process, we need to do the following:

"To get an API key for MonkeyLearn, register at http://monkeylearn.com/. Note that MonkeyLearn supports registration through GitHub, which makes the registration process really easy. For ease of use, save your API key as an environment variable as described at http://stat545.com/bit003_api-key-env-var.html. You might also want to use the usethis::edit_r_environ() function to modify .Renviron.

All functions of the package will conveniently look for your API key using Sys.getenv("MONKEYLEARN_KEY") so if your API key is an environment variable called “MONKEYLEARN_KEY” you don’t need to input it manually.

Please also create a “MONKEYLEARN_PLAN” environment variable indicating whether your Monkeylearn plan is “free”, “team”, “business” or “custom”. If you do not indicate it by default it will be “free” with a message. If your plan is “custom” you’ll need a third environment variable “MONKEYLEARN_RATE” indicating the maximum amount of requests per minute that you can make to the API. If you do not indicate it, by default it will be 120 with a message."

I've gotten the API key, but as a layman, I couldn't understand the guide on saving the api key as environment variable. Could anyone provide a step by step guide for Windows please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`monkeylearn` maintainer here, sorry for the unclear docs.

It means you need to add two lines in an R startup file called .Renviron.

```r
MONKEYLEARN_KEY="blablablayourkey"
MONKEYLEARN_PLAN="free"
```

The last line of .Renviron has to be an empty line.

To open .Renviron to edit it, you can use [`usethis::edit_r_environ()`](https://usethis.r-lib.org/reference/edit.html). After adding the two lines with your key and plan, don't forget to restart R.

Read more about startup files in general [in this resource](https://rstats.wtf/r-startup.html).

I hope this helps. Note that I don't look up Stack Overflow very often as opposed to [rOpenSci's forum](https://discuss.ropensci.org/)